# Benefit to using angular directive as comment?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

So far I've only been using Directives as `Elements` or `Attributes` is the `Comment` style directive really only a style choice?

```
app.directive('heading', [function () {
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'M',
        template: '<header> <h1>The First Title</h1> <h2>2nd Title</h2> </header>'
    };
}])
```

Directive used as **E**lement, **A**ttribute, **C**lass and Co**m**ment:

```
<heading></heading>

<p heading></p>

<div class="heading"></div>

<!-- directive: heading -->
```

Is it just a dev readability style preference? Or is there any performance differences, or other? At first glance it seems that the comment would have less usability, you could give values to an element, attach more classes to a class or attribute etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the angular docs:

> Best Practice: Comment directives were commonly used in places where
>   the DOM API limits the ability to create directives that spanned
>   multiple elements (e.g. inside  elements). AngularJS 1.2
>   introduces ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end as a better solution to
>   this problem. Developers are encouraged to use this over custom
>   comment directives when possible

--

> Best Practice: Prefer using directives via tag name and attributes
>   over comment and class names. Doing so generally makes it easier to
>   determine what directives a given element matches.

So, unless it's your only choice for some reason, don't use them.